# Distance returns null for Mongodb 2.6

Tags: mongodb

I have just upgraded mongodb from 2.4 to 2.6.
Now when I run the query

```
$hospitals=$qb->select('distance','title','date','photos','description')
                ->field('coordinates')
                ->near((float)$lat, (float)$lng)
                ->limit(9)
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute()
                ->toArray();
```

distance is always null. 
is this a bug or something ?

PS:$lat & $lng are OK!

Comment: Does it return something in previous version? Also why not to try actually mongoshell?

Comment: I'm using the mongodb Doctrine ODM, it works fine with geoNear, but not with near..

Comment: Ahh! The format changed recently. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-legacy-coordinate-pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your model has the `distance` field annotated with [`@Distance`](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#distance). This only works with the [geoNear](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/geoNear/) command. I've updated ODM's documentation in [PR #851](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/pull/851), so that change should be reflected on the main website within a day or two.

For some reason, the documentation stated that this worked with the `near()` query builder method, which uses MongoDB's [`$near`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) query operator. That's incorrect, as the `$near` operator does not return a calculated distance. Alvin mentioned using the [`$meta`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/meta/) projection operator, but `geoNearDistance` is currently an undocumented feature in the server (only `textScore` is publicly documented).

Based on your original example code, the following should work:

```
$hospitals = $qb->select('title', 'date', 'photos', 'description')
                ->geoNear( (float) $lat, (float) $lng )
                ->limit(9)
                ->getQuery()
                ->execute()
                ->toArray();
```

`field()` is only needed with `$near`. `geoNear()` (i.e. the `geoNear` command) will use whatever location field is included in the geospatial index. Also, you do not need to project the `distance` field, since it is injected by ODM after the result comes back from MongoDB. Also, your documents in MongoDB should never actually have a `distance` field stored within them. See [`Builder::execute()`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/ea4d5e7835c8c484b8a23ffca8c1a65cbb22f83a/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Query/Query.php#L232) for the exact code involved in populating the `distance` field.

Comment: Hi again ! :D
You are right , my distance field is annotaded @distance.
But then again if it only works with geoNear , does that mean I can't use $mindistance ? because it only works with $near..

Comment: The `$near` and `$nearSphere` operators support `$minDistance`. The `geoNear` command supports a `minDistance` option. See the unit tests associated with [SERVER-9395](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9395) in ([this commit](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/commit/53dab689a519b4daf6a5c4772123b74616c0283b)) for examples, since this is not yet covered in the MongoDB documentation. You might also want to read [this blog post](http://emptysqua.re/blog/paging-geo-mongodb/) from the engineer that implemented `minDistance`.

Answer (score 0):

In the shell you would do something like

```
t = db.test
t.insert({_id: 0, loc: [0,0]})
t.insert({_id: 0, loc: [1,1]})
t.ensureIndex({loc: "2d"})
t.find({loc: {$near: [0,0]}}, {dist: {$meta: "geoNearDistance"}})
```

Which results in

```
{ "_id" : 0, "loc" : [  0,  0 ], "dist" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 1, "loc" : [  1,  1 ], "dist" : 1.4142135623730951 }
```

Comment: Could you translate this to Doctrine ?

Comment: I don't think Doctrine has been fully updated to support all the new driver and MongoDB features yet. I can't find any references to geoNearDistance in Doctrine :(

Comment: @Sekai: The `$meta` project operator cannot be used with Doctrine's query builder, based on how [`select()`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/blob/4a75fa738dc8e4fbf99b3de4f729e1750b2102e0/lib/Doctrine/MongoDB/Query/Builder.php#L1188) is implemented. I've opened an issue to track this feature in [doctrine/mongodb #170](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb/issues/170). That said, you can use this syntax with the basic `find()` method (not using the query builder), since the project fields array is passed as-is to the driver.